# Image not showing in TSpeedButton

Tags: c++, image, c++builder, vcl

I'm working with Embarcadero C++Builder. I'm using the `TSpeedButton` component with a `.bmp` image.
No matter what format I try, everything looks great in the IDE, but when I compile and generate the `.exe` file and then start the application, there are no images. There is the text with a small white square on the `TSpeedButton`. I have tried the `.png`, `.jpg`, `.bmp`, `.ico` formats. Is there any solution to my issue?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Load a bmp image on Tspeedbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60153693/c-load-a-bmp-image-on-tspeedbutton)

Comment: Can you copy the button here please? You can copy the button (Ctrl+C), then paste it as text (in DFM format) or directly exact the source from .dfm file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution of my issue. it was just a problem of compatibility mode applied by default by windows 10. I have just disabled the running of the application under compatibility mode Win XP SP2 and then no showing issue.

Thanks for all your support.

Answer (score 1):

TSpeedButton has property `NumGlyphs` which indicates how many images `Glyph` contains. If you have only one image, then set `NumGlyphs = 1`.

Additionally, you can have separate images for disabled, hovered and pressed (down) buttons. In that case, multiple images are stored on the same bitmap next to each other in a horizontal raw; every image must have the same size. For instance, a bitmap 128x32px provides 4 images, 32x32px each.

Worth of mention that the **bottom-left** pixel indicates the transparent color, i.e., pixels of that color do not get drawn.

Comment: Does this aim to address the problem "_everything looks great in the IDE but when I compile and I generate the .exe file and then starting the application there are no image_"? If so, can you clarify how?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes it does. IDE ignores `NumGlyphs` property in design mode, and if `NumGlyphs = 4` (meaning that 4 images should be provided in 2*2 layout), but, in reality, there is only one image, then the program displays only the top-left quarter of the picture.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but perhaps you should add that to the answer? The bitmap's dimensions should be _Xsize = Ysize * NumGlyphs_  which means a 1*4 layout if NumGlyphs = 4.

Comment: I updated the answer with more info regarding image placement on the bitmap when NumGlyphs > 1

Comment: So, what you are saying is that if `NumGlyphs` is set to 4 when the bitmap have the dimensions `Xsize = Ysize` it could explain OP:s problem? I wasn't aware that was possible. When I loaded a square bitmap in the IDE, NumGlyphs was set to 1 automatically. When I loaded a `Xsize = Ysize*4` image in the IDE, NumGlyphs was set to 4. I never tried changing it manually. I need to try it out later.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `NumGlyphs` is 1 by default. When a new `Glyph` is assigned, `NumGlyphs` is updated automatically **only if** the new bitmap's `Width` is an **even multiple** of its `Height`. In that case, if the quotient of `Width div Height` is 1..4, `NumGlyphs` is set to that value, otherwise `NumGlyphs` is set to 1.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok, so if one places 3 images in the bitmap, NumGlyphs won't get updated automatically? The doc says that "_If the bitmap contains multiple images, specify the number of images in the bitmap with the NumGlyphs property_" but it does not mention that it will calculate, and then set `NumGlyphs` automatically for some values but not for others. As it happened, I only tried 1 and 4. :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo "*if one places 3 images in the bitmap, NumGlyphs won't get updated automatically?*" - it will, if the bitmap's width is exactly 3x its height. "*The doc ... does not mention that it will calculate*" - what I described is what really happens, I looked at `TSpeedButton`'s source code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I misunderstood the _even_ multiple part (as in 2 and 4 are even and 3 is not).  Ok, then it works as I expected. I'm still not sure how to interpret the answer though. For OP it looks great in the IDE but when running the program, there is no image. Is the assumption that OP has placed a bitmap (containing only one image) where Xsize=4*Ysize in the button and because `NumGlyphs` is calculated to 4 it happens to just show the left-most 1/4 (not top-left quarter?) part of the picture - which is blank, so OP doesn't see an image?

Comment: Well, my guesses on `NumGlyph` and color transparency are based on personal experience - what problems I encountered with images on VLC controls. Maybe there is something else, but we cannot proceed without further details from OP (e.g., DFM object declaration code). Maybe OP uses 3rd-party image class available in design but not in runtime (e.g., *TMyCustomPNGFile*)

Comment: @TedLyngmo it is *possible* that if the BMP dimensions are such that `NumGlyphs` gets misinterpreted, and if there *happens* to be a pixel in the middle of the BMP that gets mistakenly used for transparency, then that *could* explain the OP's symptom. Hard to say for sure without seeing the actual BMP file the OP is using