# Load a bmp file into a TSpeedButton

Tags: c++, image, button, c++builder, vcl

Using Embarcadero C++Builder, does anyone know how to manually load a `.bmp` file into a `TSpeedButton` using the `Glyph` property, setting a path to the image, not with the Object Inspector?

Comment: There is no answer on this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151358/c-image-on-tspeedbutton-issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Glyph`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Buttons.TSpeedButton.Glyph) property is a [`TBitmap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap), so you can use the [`TBitmap::LoadFromFile()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TGraphic.LoadFromFile) method to load a new glyph from a file:

```cpp
speedbutton->Glyph->LoadFromFile("filename.bmp");
```

Note: "***Glyph** can provide up to four images within a single bitmap. All images must be the same size and next to each other in a horizontal row.*"